# Changing the value of an address using **

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have read that it means a pointer to a pointer. But in the code below I was able to change the value of an address.

```
int main() {

    int x = 23;           // initializing variable X = 23
    int *myVar = &x;      // Creating a pointer to the address of X
    *myVar = 566;         // My attempt at changing the value of X address
    cout << x << endl;    // Printing out X with new value

}
```

And it works out. How is this possible? Does ** mean the value of an address?

Comment: You never used `**` in this snippet.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between an address and a pointer?

Comment: You never changed the value of address of `x`.

Comment: @AlanStokes An address is the location of `X`on the memory, and a pointer is a variable that points to that address. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I thought I used it in the 5th line inside the snippet. Where I put asterisk in front of myVar, `*myVar = 566`. I understood it to be `**myVar = 566`. Or does it mean `*&x = 566` instead?

Comment: @AjeetShah I never? What have I changed from the code above? Please clarify this. Is this the same as the plain classic `x=566`?

Comment: @syafihakim by `*myVar = 566` you are changing the value stored at address referred by `myVar`. `myVar` contains the address of `x` and `*myVar` refers to value at that address. BTW if you manually **change** the address value like this: `myVar = 1234567` will result in an **error**

Answer (score 6):

Here the `*` mean 2 different things:

- `int *myVar = &x;` The `*` means that `myVar` is a pointer
- `*myVar = 566;` Here the `*` means that you access the value that the pointer is pointing at

So basically,

```
int x = 23;           // 'x' is 23
int *myVar = &x;      // 'myVar' points to 'x'
*myVar = 566;         // Assign 566 to the value that 'myVar' is pointing at (which is 'x')
cout << x << endl;    // Print 'x'
```

---

You are correct that `**` would mean a pointer to a pointer (or accessing the value of the pointer of a pointer):

```
int a = 0; //'a' is 0
int* pa = &a; //'pa' is pointing to 'a'
int** ppa = &pa; //'ppa' is pointing to 'pa'

*pa = 1; //'a' is 1
**ppa = 2' //'a' is 2
```

Comment: I'd like to add, * basically is a dereference operator. If you're using it outside of a pointer declaration, an easy way to think is, that * gets the object the pointer is pointing to. (And so, ** 'dereferences' the pointer by two levels, to get you the object.)

Comment: @Meraj99 Oh I get it, is it like reversing it?

Answer (score 1):

As  Theodoros Chatzigiannakis noted in comment, your question is mistitled, since there is no usage of `**` in the code shown.

That aside, your statement that the code is changing the value of an address is mistaken.    The reason is that `*` has different meanings in declarations and statements (or expressions).

The declaration (including initialisation)

```
int *myVar = &x;
```

declares `myVar` as a pointer to `int`, and initialises it to have the value of `&x` (the address of `x`).

The statement

```
*myVar = 566;
```

then changes the `int` at the address stored in `myVar`, to have the value `566`.   Since `myVar` was previously initialised with `&x`, the effect is changing `x` to have the value `566`.   The `*` in this case is said to dereference `myVar` - it accesses the `int` whos address is stored in `myVar` (in this case, since `*myVar` is to the left of an assignment operator, to assign a value to that `int`).

Comment: So this is the same as changing the value using the classic `X=566`, right? So, what should I do if I want to change the value of the address? For example,  the integer 23 occupies the address 0x213e4. Then I would like to wipe 23 completely from 0x213e4 and change it to be 566. How???

Comment: Why do you want to modify something that is at a specific address like `0x213E4`?   [Yes, I do know how to do it - I'm not convinced it is a good idea to tell you, since there are few good reasons and many poor reasons to attempt such things - and the common result is undefined behaviour anyway].

Comment: Yeah, I don't even know why I would do such thing. But since, you have told me those reasons why I shouldn't do it, then I would not bother about that for now.